# Why is there a white piece of white in the lower left corner of my contour plot?

Tags: python, contourf

I have some grided data, like as followed pressure.txt.
I wish I can draw a contour plot.
I have finined the code.
But it seems some problems, like in my plot, there is a piece of white in the lower left.
I do not why.

[image]

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a1,b1,c1 = np.loadtxt("pressure.txt", unpack=True)
a2,b2,c2 = np.loadtxt("temperature.txt", unpack=True)
a3,b3,c3 = np.loadtxt("sl.txt", unpack=True)

x1=a1.reshape(51,16)
y1=b1.reshape(51,16)
z1=c1.reshape(51,16)



fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8), ncols=3)

cet1=ax1.contourf(x1, y1, z1, 100, cmap="jet")
ax1.set_aspect(aspect=1)
ax1.set_title("Pressure, [MPa]", fontname='Helvetica', fontsize = 12)
cet1_bar=fig.colorbar(cet1, ax=ax1, aspect=60)
cet1_bar.outline.set_visible(False)
ax1.set_xticks([0,2.5,5])
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=12, fontname="Times New Roman")
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=12, fontname="Times New Roman")
plt.savefig("Fig01.png",dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

This is the preesure.txt file：

```
0   0   1.77019175
0.166666657 0   1.768095875
0   0.100000001 1.715081125
0.166666657 0.100000001 1.713992063
0.333333313 0   1.766
0.333333313 0.100000001 1.712870938
0.49999997  0   1.766
0.49999997  0.100000001 1.713170156
0.833333254 0   1.766
0.833333254 0.100000001 1.714740406
1.166666627 0   1.766
1.166666627 0.100000001 1.716890156
1.499999881 0   1.766
1.499999881 0.100000001 1.724811125
1.874999881 0   1.766
1.874999881 0.100000001 1.736053
2.249999762 0   1.766
2.249999762 0.100000001 1.742682156
2.624999762 0   1.766
2.624999762 0.100000001 1.746366844
2.999999762 0   1.766
2.999999762 0.100000001 1.753380719
3.399999857 0   1.766
3.399999857 0.100000001 1.760403219
3.799999952 0   1.766
3.799999952 0.100000001 1.762016344
4.199999809 0   1.766
4.199999809 0.100000001 1.76242775
4.599999905 0   1.766
4.599999905 0.100000001 1.762552344
5   0   1.766
```

I have to delete some data in the pressure.txt.
I do not know how to upload the file, so I have to paste it partly in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the key point in my question.
I should sort data in the "Pressure.txt".
I have tried to fix it.
Each column of data should be arranged from small to large, and no problem will occur.
I mean, the first column and second column because they are used to locate the position.

Answer (score 0):

For me, everything worked when I passed the optional parameter nchunk=10 to the function contourf. It should fix this issue!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35326250)